# Base64 algorithm with multiple result of a factor in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, encryption, base64

I have the following problem: I need to convert a certain content to base64 to prevent some problems with characters, and after this conversion I need to encrypt this data with one Aes algorithm with a key length of 16. The problem occurs when the result of the base64 algorithm returns a response with size that is not a multiple of 16 causing problems on encryption, considering that the size of the original content are multiples of 16. How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Ever heard of padding?

Answer (score 0):

Pad the result of the base4 encoding to be a multiple of 16.

Answer (score 0):

base64 encoder encodes your 8-bit data using 6-bits per character, so for every 3 bytes of input data you get 4 bytes of output data (plus padding to 4-byte boundary). So data size passed to AES algorithm may have length which is not multiple of 16.

Please check documentation for your AES library - chances are that it can handle this internally if you call special function for last chunk of data (e.g. `EVP_EncryptFinal_ex` in OpenSSL). Another solution is to pad data to 16-byte boundary in your code before encrypting it.

Answer (score 0):

Most AES implementations support padding such as PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5). This will add the required padding bytes on encryption and remove then on decryption.

AES is a data based function and as such accepts any bytes so it's not necessary to Base64 encode prior to encryption. Encrypted data is just bytes, not characters, so the output may need to be encoded with a method such as Base64 or hexadecimal based on the usage such as the need for printable characters.